# How to get the product type by SKU?

Tags: magento2, product, collection

I have a bunch of SKUs in a DB table and I want to get the respective products in my **for each** logic.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the interface below.

> Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\GetProductTypesBySkusInterface

```
...
private $getProductTypeBySku; 
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\GetProductTypesBySkusInterface $getProductTypeBySku
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->getProductTypeBySku = $getProductTypeBySku;
    ...
}

public function loadProductBySku($sku)
{
    return $this->getProductTypeBySku->execute([$sku]);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean get product type? If so yes this do it. If you mean load product by SKU no this won't do it. Also this will only work if you are using MSI https://github.com/magento/inventory/blob/80311a81ff3dff64e5be926188db5517a550f0b3/InventoryConfiguration/Model/IsSourceItemManagementAllowedForSku.php#L45

Answer (score 0):

You can load product by sku use below code:

```
...
private $productRepository; 
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}

public function loadProductBySku($sku)
{
    return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
}
```